# Screenflow file type convert to AVI?

Tags: macos, video

I've got a couple of large files 2 - 3GB each which were of a training course where the instructor used Screenflow on the Mac to record all his keypresses.

I'm currently on a PC..

**Problem:**  how to convert from .screenflow (and associated .scc files) to AVI or something a PC can play?

**Problem2:**  If I borrow a Mac can I d/load http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm (which I think was the package) and convert the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `scc` is a proprietary format. I wasn't able to open it using `VLC`.

---

ScreenFlow can export to `h.264` and even to `WMV` if you have the Flip4Mac components. It offers several different presents for this:

[image]

You can also export to flash (`.f4v`) and directly to YouTube.

---

According to the web site, you have some trial restrictions:

> Trial Download
>   Your exported QuickTime movies will be watermarked but the application will be fully functional.

If you can live with that, you can borrow a Mac and convert there.

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel - trying that today and I'll post back results!

Comment: Needs a newish version of OSX.. trying again soon on another Mac!

Comment: I found that the watermark is really quite big... but ok.  Another gotcha was that the Mac could read fine off an NTFS disk, but wouldn't write.  So wrote to desktop, then to a usb key :-)